# Find main function in a source code

Tags: c

I am learning by looking at this source code of other projects..I have code a source code of python.. I see several *.c files but I don't know to navigate through it.Is there way to  find out main  function in source code

Answer (score 1):

Those *.c files are supposed to be the declarations for including c source codes.
You should have a look to some more files that could probably contain c codes.
main function can just be found by pasting the source code in a txt file and then use grep(for linux) command.
Happy CODING!